# Postfix new mail notification to gmail

Tags: email, postfix, ubuntu-10.04

I've got a Ubuntu server set up with Postfix, it can send and receive emails just fine. However, I already have a widget on my computer which notifies me of new gmail emails. I'd like it to also notify me of mail to the server.

The easiest way (conceptually) I can see of doing this is to set the server to send a 'New Mail' message to my gmail account.

I don't want to just forward the mail, I want it to 'ping' in the same content-less kind of way facebook does.

Anyone have any ideas about how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Procmail](http://www.procmail.org/).

Sample config:

```
:0:
* ^To.*account@domain.*
{
  :0 c
  ! account@gmail.com

  :0
  username
}
```